# Use a different passport for your home country

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, passport-stamps

What if you have two passports from two different countries (for example France and India) and you visit India but you did not bring your Indian passport, will India consider you "French" and stamp your passport with a visa (lets say for this example that you get a visa upon entry), and thus disregard that you are actually a holder of Indian passport and Indian citizen?

Is there some problem with this (because I assume India would know that I have an Indian passport also) - or can I always just choose which passport I use to whichever country I travel to even if it is that I go to one of my "home-countries"?

Comment: Depends on the nation. Generally, making a visa application for a country where you are a citizen could be false testimony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that in several countries, if you hold a passport to that country, you must use that passport to enter that country.

As a practical matter, I doubt they would ever figure it out if you used another one.

Comment: Depends where but in this day of electronic tracking and inter-connected databases they do. When we ask here, in Ecuador, for our migratory movements they bring up a list that shows all the different passport numbers used to enter the country.